# How can I execute requests on my Microsoft Azure Database from my Android app

Tags: javascript, android, azure

I have an SQL Azure database and I want to link it to my android application and do requests on it (insert,select...) .
I created a mobile service following this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/) and inserted data in my database.

I want to know what is the good way to excute requests from my android app.
I found that [solution](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/) but I am afraid that I can't execute all the requests I want like in SQL.

Another solution that I found is script but can we write javascript code in an android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile services (also known as App Service - Mobile App) is out-of-the-box solution that allows you to expose your database tables as REST API endpoints that implement OData protocol, allowing you to write queries from your client (Android) app code and have them execute on database level.

However, if you are not satisfied with what App Service - Mobile App can offer and you want to build more sophisticated custom REST services, then you should aim to create App Service - API App or App Service - Web App and deploy Web API on it.

Then you would issue regular HTTP requests from your Android app to App Service REST endpoints.

[App Service - Web App Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/)

[App Service - API App Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/)

Comment: Thank you Admir. And what is in your opinion the best solution ?